# changing facebook comments plugin attributes

Tags: facebook, plugins, comments

This may be incredibly simple but I can't seem to find anything on it after searching for a couple of hours. I've added a FB comments plugin to a website, to be used as a page tab and everything is loading fine and it works as expected in general, however I want to be able to change the various links in the comment box. For example remove the 'like' link or the 'reply' link.

At the moment it also shows my age with the comment which is very strange and there is no pagination. Other pages I've looked at seem to be able to control this though when I look at the fb-comment tag and the css I can't see anything to control it.

For instance in this page (the ?why tab) there is pagination and no like/reply/age:
http://www.facebook.com/FoodRevolutionCommunity?sk=app_168878106492743

I've tried with both HTML5 and the xfbml with no luck, I guess it's better to use the HTML5 code.

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Richard, i am not sure how much you have installed on your site, with out a link to follow.  To enable the moderation tools you need to add a few open graph tags to the head of your pages that have the comments box.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

fb:app_id and my app id are what enable the tools.  NOTE:  *from my understanding you cannot remove the like and reply links.*

An example from one of my apps that has a comments box on page.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:anotherfeed="http://www.shawnsspace.com/ns#">
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# anotherfeed: http://ogp.me/ns/apps/anotherfeed#">
            <title>Another Feed Install Wizard</title>
        <meta property="og:title" content="Another Feed Install Wizard"/>
        <meta property="og:description" content="Use Another Feed Install Wizard to generate Time Line style Feeds for your pages and applications."/>
        <meta property="og:type" content="anotherfeed:wizard"/>
        <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $this_ogimage; ?>"/>
        <meta property="og:site_name" content="ShawnsSpace"/>   
        <meta property="fb:app_id" content="135669679827333"/>
        <meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo ''.$url.'';?>"/>
</head>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Shawn, I added a link to show what I'm after.

Comment: There are 2 versions of the comments box.  html5 and fbml.

<div class="fb-comments" data-href="example.com" data-num-posts="2" data-width="500"></div>

<fb:comments href="example.com" num_posts="2" width="500"></fb:comments>

Comment: you can create paging with data-num-posts="" on the html5 and num_posts="" for the fbml version.  The one you posted was the old version of the comments box which you can not create new anymore.  The reply feature replaces the message feature.

Comment: I'm using the html5 div and I have the num_posts set to 2 but still no page nation with 10 comments. Also added all the meta tags. The other thing I notice is that I can only see my own comments not others.

Answer (score 1):

I have just updated a set of instructions that includes complete SEO of Facebook comments. Come check it out if you need a little more help.
http://www.reachhighdesign.com/km/facebook-comments-optomized-for-seo.html